# How do accessors prevent hackers from accessing your private data?

Tags: variables, private, accessor

Whenever a tutorial first introduces accessors, they always start off with a public variable initialized in the class or object. There is then a method to print that public value. Then they make it private to show that it is hidden to outside users.

For example:

```
int _dayOfWeek;
public int dayOfWeek
    {
        get
        {
            return _dayOfWeek;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value > 0 && value < 8) _dayOfWeek = value;
        }
    }
```

What's stopping hackers from just using these accessors to get and change your values?

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulation doesn't help against hackers. It helps against mistaken use of your code. See [the wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) article for more information on the uses of encapsulation.

By making your private data accessible to programmers who use your code it is very hard to make sure that they use it properly. If you control all access to your data then you can ensure that it is indeed used as you intended it to be used.

Providing accessors to your private data is usually a code smell that indicates improper encapsulation. It is only slightly better than exposing your data. You want to expose to the users functionality and not raw data.